# Proving that $n$'th integral of $1/x$ belongs to a certain family.

Tags: integration, derivatives, soft-question, logarithms

Let us calculate the first few iterated integrals of $$f(t) = \frac 1 t$$

It is well known from high school

$$I_1\{f,t\}(t) = \int \frac 1 t dt = \log(t) + C_1$$
Then in our first calculus course at University we maybe derive:
$$I_2\{f,t\}(t) = \int \log(t) dt = t(\log(t)-1) + C_1t + C_2$$

We can furthermore verify :

$$I_3\{f,t\}(t) = \int t(\log(t)-1) dt = \frac{t^2}{4}(2\log(t)-3)+C_1t^2+C_2t+C_3$$

This seems to follow a pattern. Let $P_1,P_2,P_3$ be polynomials. We can now find them so that $P_1(t)P_2(\log(t)) + P_3(t)$ equals any of the above expressions and $P_3$ is created by integration constants.

Can we prove that any $N$ times iterated integral of $f(t) = \frac 1 t$ will follow this pattern?

$$I_0\{f,t\}(t_0) = f(t_0)\\I_N\{f,\xi\}(t_0) = \left(\int I_{N-1}\{f,\xi\} d\xi\right)(t_0)$$

Comment: Is the antiderivative of a polynomial times $\log t$ plus a polynomial also a polynomial times $\log t$ plus a polynomial? It's sufficient to examine the antiderivative of $t^n \log t$ where $n = 1,\,2,\,3\,\ldots$ If so, then the result you want is immediate by mathematical induction. If not, then you've probably found a counterexample in verifying "not".

Comment: To be precise you get an integration constant each time you integrate so this adds a polynomial in $t$ to your results.

Comment: @frog you are correct. I shall fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $$\forall n\in\mathbb N,\int_0^t u^n\log(u)=\left[\dfrac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}\times \log(u)\right]_0^t-\int_0^t \dfrac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}\times \dfrac{1}{u}\text{d}u=\dfrac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}\log(t)-\dfrac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2} $$

So if $f \in \mathbb R[x] \times \log(x)+\mathbb R[x]=L$ then $$g(x)=\int_0^x f(u)\text{d}u,g \in L$$

Comment: Good. Thank you! This is what I suspected too. How neat. You are using integration by parts, no?

Comment: yes, I am using  integration by parts